# floated element and overflow in css and html work

Tags: html, css, overflow

When you use `overflow:hidden` to the main wrapper that are contain floated element, how does overflow fix the flow of floated element?

Comment: can you create a demo of your code using http://jsfiddle.net and share? That will be more helpful!

Comment: What do you mean by `fix the flow of floated element` ?

Comment: why do you need a demo, I am talking about float problem, overflow:hidden work just like clearfix solution, my question is why does it work like this

Comment: I think the demo is required because no one actually understands your question.  If you give us a demo, then someone might be able to help.